# Chrome headless driver never makes it to website

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Otherwise: Anyone have any good pypeteer guides they can link me to?

Hi guys, i'm trying to run chrome headless. This is my code:

```
def init_chrome(profile, headless, proxy: str = "159.197.220.31:5594"):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    if headless:
        options.add_argument("--headless")
    print('headless set')
    options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
    options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=8000")
    options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy}')
    options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir=browser-profiles/chrome/{profile}")
    options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
    options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["disable-popup-blocking"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    options.add_argument(
        "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,
                              executable_path=fr'{getcwd()}\chromedriver.exe')
    print('driver launched')
    driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
        "source": """
        Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
          get: () => undefined
        })
      """
    })
    # driver.set_window_size(1200, 900)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    return driver
```

This is the output:

```
headless set
driver launched
```

As you can see, the driver is launched, but it never goes to the page. It just sits there and eats resources. What am I doing wrong? For context, this works fine when `headless=False`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need [--no-sandbox] to by pass OS security and if you using Windows add
[--disable-gpu] to enable headless.

It should look like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') 
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu') 
options.add_argument('start-maximized')

driver =webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= path to your browser, options=options)
driver.get("http://google.com/")
driver.quit()
```